# Question in one of the proofs of Terry Tao's Analysis I on chapter on Integration

Tags: real-analysis

We have this inequality:
\begin{equation}
0 \leq \overline{\int_I} \max(f,g) - \underline{\int_I} \max(f,g) \leq 4\epsilon
\end{equation}
for every $\epsilon$. The next line says since $\overline{\int_I} \max(f,g) - \underline{\int_I} \max(f,g)$ does not depend on $\epsilon$, we thus see that $\overline{\int_I} \max(f,g) - \underline{\int_I} \max(f,g)=0$ .

I don't understand the argument that if the difference does not depend on $\epsilon$ it is equal to zero. why?

Comment: [Sandwich theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem). Make $\epsilon\to0$, what happens to the expression in the middle of the inequality?

Comment: $\epsilon$ is strictly greater than 0, as specified early on in the theorem. The reason quoted is not that $\epsilon \to 0$, it is that there is no $\epsilon$ dependence in the middle term.That is the relationship I was trying to understand. @Jean-ClaudeArbaut

Comment: You can apply sandwich theorem *because* of the reason quoted...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is about a certain definite number $a\in{\mathbb R}$, maybe defined in a complicated way. In addition you know that for every $\epsilon>0$ the inequality
$$0\leq a\leq\epsilon$$
holds. This is only possible when in fact $a=0$. Because, when $a>0$ we could choose $\epsilon:={a\over2}>0$ and then would have
$$0<a\leq{a\over2}\ ,$$
which is impossible.

Comment: Thanks @ChristianBlatter